# How to Extract an Html element from a snipet of Html with HtmlAgilityPack?

Tags: c#, html, code-snippets

Here is the Html code:

```
<table style="border:1px solid #000">
  <tr style="background:#ddd;">
    <td width="150">TableEle1</td>
    <td width="150">TableEle2</td>
    <td width="150">TableEle3</td>
    <td width="150">TableEle4</td>
    <td width="150">TableEle5</td>
    <td width="150">TableEle6</td>
    <td width="150">TableEle7</td>
    <td width="150">TableEle8</td>
  </tr>
```

And here is the code I use to extract the table element 1 (but not successful)

```
htmlHelper.SetNode(@"//td/text()='TableEle1'");
```

Is there any advice for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a blend of HtmlAgilityPack and Linq to get the desired td node.

```
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();            
document.LoadHtml("[your HTML string]");            
var node = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//td/text()");
var tdNode = node.Where(s => s.InnerText == "TableEle1").Select(s => s);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just another question, if I have multiple table like the table above in my html file, how can I let my code to just look for td element in the first table only.

Comment: Appreciate if you first UpVote my answer.

Comment: Specify the id to get the desired table simple, e.g. //table[@id='theTableId']

Comment: The problem with that is all the tables are the same, only different in Table Element and don't have table ID

Comment: Since the minimum rep power to UpVote is 15, so right now I cant do that.
Whenever I got 15 rep power, I will get back to your post immediately ;)

Comment: Simply do this, var node = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table").First();